# Error changing title format

Tags: titlesec, chapter-page

I'm trying to use the format of chapter title like this
[image]

I used this code:

```
 \newlength\chapnumb
 \setlength\chapnumb{4cm}
 \newcommand{\chaptertitlefont}{\normalfont\sffamily\Huge}
 \titleformat{\chapter}[block]
 {\normalfont\sffamily}{}{0pt}
 {\parbox[b]{\chapnumb}{%
 \fontsize{120}{110}\selectfont\thechapter}%
 \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{%
 \raggedleft%
 \hfill{\chaptertitlefont#1}\\
 \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{0.4pt}}}
 \titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]
 {\normalfont\sffamily}{}{0pt}
 {\parbox[b]{\chapnumb}{%
 \mbox{}}%
 \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{%
 \raggedleft%
 \hfill{\chaptertitlefont#1}\\
 \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{0.4pt}}}
```

But this code gives me this result:
[image]

with an error:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \ttlf@chapter.
```

Can any one help me please,  i tried to use the package " titlesec" gives me an error also.

Thank you in advance

Comment: After more than 6 (almost 7) years you should know, that posting code snippets instead of a MWE is not advisable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working solution with a much cleaner code.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}% if you want to use the default CM fonts
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newlength\chapnumb
\setlength\chapnumb{4cm}

\newcommand{\chaptertitlefont}{\normalfont\sffamily\Huge}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\sffamily}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\belabedtitle{\thechapter}}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]
  {\normalfont\sffamily}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\belabedtitle{\vphantom{0}}}

\newcommand{\belabedtitle}[2]{%
   \makebox[\chapnumb][l]{\fontsize{120}{0}\selectfont #1}%
   \parbox[b]{\dimeval{\textwidth-\chapnumb}}{%
     \raggedleft
     \chaptertitlefont #2\\\vspace{0.5ex}
     \hrule
   }%
  }

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

The `oneside` option is just to have the two chapters side-by-side in the picture.

[image]

The macro `\belabeltitle` is the key. It takes two arguments: the first one is explicitly supplied, the second one is supplied by `titlesec` and is the chapter title.

Comment: really thank you, thank you a lot, it works